# How to add search functionality in Google Map SDK in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-search-api

i am newbie in iOS Development and Newbie to Google map SDK i want to put a Search Functionality in my Application through URL Schema of Google Map it is Possible if it is Possible then Please Give me solution for this, or any Resource for it.
thanks.

Comment: what kind of search? what's the input and what's the output?

Comment: @nburk same as google map like as `city name` ,`country name`,`state name`, `street name` and i want to show them in to my GMSMapView.

Comment: did I answer your question? is anything still unclear? :) otherwise could you tick the green checkmark to mark the question as solved please :)

Comment: ? do you still need help? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for this, you can't do this with only the Google Maps iOS SDK itself.

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600
>   Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use
>   to place markers or position the map.

The user can enter any kind of address, and the Geocoding API will return the specific coordinates, so that you can display it on a map.

Comment: but you have any resource then please give me.

Comment: check out this tutorial by a google engineer, it's awesome https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkYPE7vbttc

Comment: When i use my Api key then error is `This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.`

Comment: ok, that's a new question :) can you mark this question as solved and post a new one specific to this problem please :)

Comment: i do that can you help me for this now?

Comment: here which key are added in to geocoding when i added my google map iOS sdk key then it is give me error.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers suggest, you will need to use [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Basically, you'll need to send requests to the api and parse the information you want from the JSON object returned (you can also use XML).

**Very** basic example for receiving a json response from the api:

```
- (void)sendGeoCodingRequest:(NSString *)parameters {


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=%@" YOUR_KEY];
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

        if (httpResponse.statusCode != 200 || error || ![data length]) {
            NSLog(@"Error fetching auto complete results: %@", error);
        } else {

            // parse the json and do something with the result
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        }
    });
}
```

Just follow the The Google Geocoding API instructions and hopefully the code snippet will speed things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

[The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

[Google Maps API Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=us)

Google Maps SDK for iOS